# How do I add stdin_open: true, tty: true to the docker run command using google cloud run

Tags: reactjs, docker, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy a react app to google cloud run and I get this error when its ran
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.3/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /

on my local machine I am able to run it by adding the flag -it to the docker run command but I can't seem to figure out how to add this to google cloud run

Ive tried editing the command line arguments in the container but I can't get it to work

Comment: Are you working on windows environment?

Comment: No im using macos

Comment: In Cloud Run you can't execute `-it`. In fact it is not expected that you attach stdin. Can you share what actually the container does?

Comment: the last line I get in the logs is Starting the development server... then done in 3.0 seconds but the server isn't actually running because of the error I stated above, the docker container is "finished"

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a way to add stdin_open: true, tty: true to the docker run command using google cloud run.
You can add stdin_open: true, tty: true to the docker run command using the following flags:

--stdin --tty

Comment: So sorry I may be mis understanding can I add --stdin --tty to the google cloud run command? If so how?

Comment: Yes, you can add the --stdin --tty flags to the google cloud run command.
for example 
```
<code>gcloud run deploy my-service --image gcr.io/my-project/my-service --platform managed --region us-central1 --memory 512Mi --concurrency 10 --stdin --tty
</code>
```

Comment: ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) unrecognized arguments:
  --tty (did you mean '--tag'?)
  --stdin
  To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
  gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS

This is what I get in response to adding those flags to the command line